# Fastest way to stream audio via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, audio, audio-streaming

All of my audio files are coming from an external source, Google Cloud Storage. And all of the files have a public URL that can be accessed without an authorization token.

Sample URL: `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/randomId.mp3`

And my current way of streaming the audio to my client is grasping the binary and using `sendSeekable` to response

Example code

```js
const url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/randomId.mp3';

request({
  url: track.file.location,
  encoding: null,
}, (error, response, body) => {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.sendSeekable(body);
});
```

But what I saw SoundCloud did is they will request a new small chunk of `base64` audio, so no matter where the user starts playing the music, it will just response really quick, is like there own way of doing streaming `seekable`.

So my quest will be, will it be passable to do that kind of infrastructure, split up the audio and response with a small chunk bytes?

And is there any tips or best practices for streaming audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best/fastest thing to do is simply redirect to the resource.  Use 301, 302, 307, or 308 status code and a `Location` header.